# Multithreading with Java: Performance test

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Ryzen processor with 16 cores under Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and I wanted to test it with java threads. I am little bit disappointed about the performance. My expectation was that parralel computation is muchh faster, but there is only a difference of one second + plus some milliseconds.

So, as I assume my threads are not supported by multiple cores? My little test does not use any synchronization. It is just computing each matrix element. Is there any jvm optimizations or I need some arguments to run the java program?

Here is my source:

```
public class Image2DInput <T> {

  public static Integer[] dimension(Integer d0, Integer d1) {
    return new Integer[] {d0, d1};
  }

  public static Integer[] point(Integer i, Integer j) {
    return new Integer[] {i, j};
  }

  public static <T> T origin(T origin) {
    return origin;
  }

  private final T origin;
  private final BiFunction<Integer[], T, T> delta;
  private final Object[][] matrix;

  public Image2DInput(
      Integer[] dimension, 
      T origin, 
      BiFunction<Integer[], T, T> delta)
  {
    throwIfNull(dimension, "origin must not be null");
    throwIfNull(origin, "origin must not be null");
    throwIfNull(delta, "deltaFunction must not be null");
    this.origin = origin;
    this.delta = delta;
    this.matrix = new Object[dimension[0]][dimension[1]];

    if (dimension[0] > 0 && dimension[1] > 0) {
      setMatrix();
      setOrigin();
    }
  }

  private void setOrigin () {
    var d0 = matrix.length / 2;
    var d1 = matrix[0].length / 2;
    this.matrix[d0][d1] = origin;
  }

  private void setMatrix () {
    var numberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    var threads = IntStream
      .range(0, numberOfThreads)
      .mapToObj( index -> new RowWorker(index, numberOfThreads) )
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    threads.stream().forEach( t -> t.start() );
    threads.stream().forEach( t -> join(t) );
  }

  private void setSingleThreadedMatrix () {
    for (var i=0; i<matrix.length; ++i)
      for (var j=0; j<matrix[0].length; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = delta.apply(new Integer[]{i,j}, origin);
  }


  private class RowWorker extends Thread {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer offset;

    RowWorker(Integer id, Integer offset) {
      this.id = id;
      this.offset = offset;
      setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
      for (var i=id; i<matrix.length; i+=offset)
        for (var j=0; j<matrix[0].length; ++j)
          matrix[i][j] = delta.apply(new Integer[]{i,j}, origin);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public String toString () {
    var image = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i=0; i<matrix.length; ++i)
      writeRow (i, image);
    return image.toString();
  }

  private void writeRow (int i, StringBuilder image) {
    for (var j=0; j<matrix[0].length; ++j)
      image.append(at(i,j)).append(", ");
    image.replace(image.length()-2, image.length(), "\n");
  }

  private T at(int i, int j) {
    return (T) matrix[i][j];
  }
}
```

And here my testrun:

```
  @Test
  public void testPerformance () {
    final var dim = dimension(4*2560,4*1440);
    complexImage(dim, z(0.0,0.0), (p,o) -> compute(dim, p, o));
  }

  private Complex compute (Integer[] dim, Integer[] pt, Complex origin) {
    var originAt = point(dim[0] /2, dim[1] /2);
    var offset = 1.0;
    return 
      z( (pt[1]-originAt[1])*offset, -(pt[0]-originAt[0])*offset )
      .add(origin);
  }

  private String complexImage (
      Integer[] dimension, 
      Complex origin, 
      BiFunction<Integer[], Complex, Complex> delta)
  {
    var image = new Image2DInput<Complex>(dimension, origin, delta);
    return image.toString();
  }
```

Comment: This code looks hugely inefficient (for example one should never see `new Integer[]` in ‘performance’ code) and also lacks warm ups and sensible timings. I don’t think these benchmarks are particularly useful. I strongly suspect what you’re timing is the creation of 32 threads.

Comment: Agree with Boris, thread initialization is expensive,
it's better to use thread pool by `java.util.concurrent.Executors#newFixedThreadPool(int)`
and count time inside of `run` methods

Comment: Integer? Is that not optimized by the compiler? I used that for generic reasons... I used then instead FixedThreadPool and I got the same result. 16 threads are for one second faster than single threaded? BTW... I removed the toString method call.

Comment: One second faster does not say much. It is with what factor the time changes thats important. If one second corresponds to a speed up factor of 16, thats greate. If it it much less than that its not greate. However, I would guess that your algorithm is memory bounded, almost all time is spent on accessing memory. Hence you dont see any significant performance improvements when you parallelize it.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Bounded to memory, yes it is. Threads are writing all the time to the matrix. Is there a better approach? Something like, first calculate and after calculations, write to memory at once?

Comment: You need to make sure that you write the code so the CPU caches can be utilized as good as possible. (Java is not the most fun language to do that in). Try and profile how long it takes to allocate the array in the Image2DInput is taking a lot of time (probably most of the time)

Answer (score -1):

I have changed to FixedThreadPool. I did not see any difference.

```
  private void setMatrix () {
    var numberOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    var service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    IntStream
      .range(0, numberOfThreads)
      .forEach( id -> service.submit( () -> {
        for (var i=id; i<matrix.length; i+=numberOfThreads)
          for (var j=0; j<matrix[0].length; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = delta.apply(new Integer[]{i,j}, origin);
        } ));

    try {
      service.shutdown();
      service.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
  }
```